# EF Code first use for local database and production on hosting

Tags: ef-code-first

I use the newest version of Code first with Migration feature.

I use it with local database and hosted (I only change connection string in config file between Update-Database command) .

So when I run Update-Database command after change my POCO class on local database my db always successfully updates the schema. When I first time use it on a production db I successful create schema, but when I want to update it I get error that table exist in database.

It's true that it exist, but why don't i get this error when it updates the local database, where this table exist also?

Comment: Did you run the add-migration command after your POCO classes were updated?